# HTML download not correct file type

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have a download link on my html. But upon doing when I download the file the file extension is not correct. It's just says `File` instead of a `csv` file type.

```
<a href="test.csv" download="filename">Download link</a>
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: download="filename.csv"

Comment: Also, keep in mind that older browsers don't recognize `download`. https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The download attribute specifies that the target will be downloaded when a user clicks on the hyperlink.
>
> This attribute is only used if the href attribute is set.
>
> The value of the attribute will be the name of the downloaded file.
>   There are no restrictions on allowed values, and the browser will
>   automatically detect the correct file extension and add it to the file
>   (.img, .pdf, .txt, .html, etc.).
>
> If the value is omitted, the original filename is used.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

```
<a href="test.csv" download>Download link</a>
```